# Docker container only accessible by another

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have an elasticsearch container that has to be accessible by my nodejs application but I don't want my first container to be accessible by anything else that my nodejs app.

I've set a link from the nodejs app to my elasticsearch container but I did not found any option to disable any other connection.

What is the best way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a private network that is only shared by your elasticsearch container and the specific clients you want. You can also create a second network which allows your nodejs app to communicate with other containers.

Avoid using links. They're considered legacy if you're defining your own networks like below.

```
version: "2"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
  esprivate:
    driver: bridge

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:2.3.3
    networks:
      - esprivate:
    expose:
      - "9200"
      - "9300"

  nodejs:
    networks:
      - esprivate
      - backend

  other_service:
    networks:
      - backend
```

In this docker-compose.yml example, your nodejs app can refer to elasticsearch using the url `http://elasticsearch:9200`.